# How to enable/load mod_wsgi in apache server in centos 8 VPS

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, httpd, django, mod-wsgi

I am not able to enable/load module mod_wgsi in apache webserver in cent os 8 VPS. It works very easily in ubuntu by running the command `sudo apt install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` Please Help me getting set up apache for django in centos 8 by letting me know how to enable the mod_wsgi for apache. Your Help is Highly Appreciated.

The Commands I have run initially:

```
sudo yum update
sudo yum install python3-pip python3-devel httpd httpd-devel
pip3 install mod_wsgi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check this blog -

https://dataengee.blogspot.com/2022/04/django-server-setup-with-apache-with.html

it has the basic setup

Comment: Thanks a lot, Your blog is extremely helpful, and will be perfect to do the complete deployment of my django app, Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot  for the recognition. @ManavSengupta. More details in https://dataengee.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to erase your VPS and start over with a fresh installation of CentOS 8, because you have run `pip3 install mod_wsgi` and trying to clean up from this (if it's even possible) will take significantly longer than just starting fresh.

Next, you need to choose whether you want Python 3.6 or Python 3.8. By default Python 3.6 will be used, but you can switch to Python 3.8 by enabling its [AppStream](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_basic_system_settings/managing-software-packages_configuring-basic-system-settings#application-streams_managing-software-packages):

```
dnf module enable python38
```

If you chose to remain on Python 3.6, then install the `python3-mod_wsgi` package. If you chose to go with Python 3.8, then install the `python38-mod_wsgi` package.

```
dnf install python38-mod_wsgi
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Indeed It worked!. But I am not yet able to successfully deploy django website in centos apache using Ubuntu Server knowledge alone. But anyway The mod_wsgi part I asked is solved very smoothly following your given steps, thanks a lot. :)